# Why this code give me compile Time error using Interface and how i can implement this code? Please Explain?

Tags: java, interface

There are two interfaces and have common variable which is final.

```
interface abc {
    int a = 10;

    public void display();
}

interface xyz {
    int a = 20;

    public void display();
}

public class NewClass implements abc, xyz {
    public NewClass() {
        System.out.println(a);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NewClass obj = new NewClass();
        obj.display();
    }

    @Override
    public void display() {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: Wgich errors do you get?

Comment: I don't know any java but my guess would be that it's hard for the compiler to know from which interface you try to override the `display()` method...  you talk about a compile time error, don't you get an error message ?

Comment: Please explain what is confusing you?  You have two fields with the same name, what do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the  [the diamond of death](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem)

Since  **Compiler** is not smart enough to know which final variable you want to access untill you tell him which interface's `final` variable to use .

You have to specify like this

```
System.out.println(xyz.a);
```

or

```
System.out.println(abc.a);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are referring an unknown to the constructor variable `a`. You have to do:

```
System.out.println(xyz.a);
```

or

```
System.out.println(abc.a);
```

depending on which exact `a` you'd like to print.

Answer (score 2):

This field a is ambigous, you can't have 2 same fields implemented. Also - interface variables are static and final by default. You don't even need to set them as static final.

Comment: yes i know it .but Interface is not fully implementation of multiple Inheritance.

Comment: It's just a core design, this is how Java engineers decided to make it and that's it :)

Answer (score 1):

Reference to `a` is ambiguous since its present in both the interfaces which `NewClass` implements.

To resolve this, you need to specify which variable you want to reference.

use `System.out.println(abc.a)` to refer the variable in `abc` interface or `System.out.println(xyz.a)` to refer a in `xyz`

Answer (score 0):

**a is "ambiguous". It could belong to either xyz or abc. That's why the compiler screams**.

See, in this code :

```
public NewClass() {
    System.out.println(a); // a is "ambiguous". It could belong to either xyz or abc. That's why the compiler screams
}
```

Change your code to specify from which interface a must be used.like this

```
 public NewClass() {
        System.out.println(xyz.a);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats a namespace conflict.

If the interfaces do simmilar things you should extend one from the other. If not, you should name the methods differently.

```
interface abc {
    public void display();
}

interface xyz extends abc {
    int a = 20;
}
```

Also, if the common field is not strictly needed for default methods in the interface you should not define them in the interface, but in the implementing class. Else give them a proper unique name.

Or access the variables / methods like this:

```
public NewClass() {
    System.out.println(xyz.a);
}
```

But in my optinion that is bad practice..

Comment: This is not a bad practice. It makes me logical.

Answer (score 0):

there is no any variable as 'a' in class `NewClass` if you want to use variable 'a' from interface `abc` or `xyz`,,

```
public NewClass() {
    System.out.println(abc.a);
}
```

OR

```
public NewClass() {
    System.out.println(xyz.a);
}
```